# When will the promise from Angular's HttpClient.get() be rejected?

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

In our Angular codebase we commonly have http requests handled as such:

```
return this.http
  .get<Whatever>(url)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => {
     // handle successful response
  })
  .catch(e => {
     // handle errors
  });
```

Note that in the `.then()`, we do not provide a callback to handle the promise being rejected.

Are there circumstances in which this promise may actually be rejected, should we be safe and handle these scenarios too? I'm sure I am lacking some fundamental understanding of promises/angular/whatever here, and perhaps we should switch to using observables rather than always doing a .toPromise()

Comment: What happens when your get request returns a non 2xx response? which path does your code take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of 40x and 50x responses in the http, the promise will be rejected.
In case of 20x and 30x responses in the http, the promise will be resolved.

The catch callback after the then() is the rejection callback. Hence if the http request fails or gets an error, the code inside the catch block will be run.

And you are right, it is better to use observables for http methods.